# How to get the hostname for Adobe Connect API

Tags: adobe-connect

I'm trying to authenticate my account with the api, I've been following the documentation, but unable to load the api at all because of the host name. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the whole concept, but where would I find the hostname to replace 'example.com' with.

```
https://example.com/api/xml?action=common-info
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in any of the links you might have to a existing piece of content.  So if you've got a presentation at:

```
https://connect.myserver.com/test-training-course
```

you'd log in with:

```
https://connect.myserver.com/api/xml?action=login&login=myusername&password=mypassword
```